# Java array with specific keys

Tags: java, arrays

Can you make a java array with hashes as key, without using HashMap/HashTable (only arrays allowed!)?

the array should look like this:
[hashkey] -> [javaobject]

The hashkey is calculated by a function (for example it could be "-51")

Answer (score 1):

No you can't.  The *indexes* (not keys) of an array are integers between 0 and `array.length - 1`.

Furthermore, Java arrays are not sparse.  If you could (hypothetically) allocate an array large enough that it could accommodate all possible `int` values as "keys", it would occupy 2^32 * N bytes, where N is the size of a pointer.  That would be grossly wasteful way to implement an associative array / hash.

(And you can't, because the theoretical largest possible array size allowed by the JLS is 2^31 - 1 elements!)

---

Having said that, there are special purpose map classes that will map an `int` key to a reference using much less memory than a `HashMap`.

For example: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is a pitfall for your appp..
Remember that hashcode is not an I'd and java can generate collisions breaking the integrity of the program

For example: "Aa" and "BB" have the same hashcode:  **2112**

So if you have an array of integers ( hashcodes) an suddenly those 2 guys come to play, you will never ever find why the code doesn't work

Use concrete classes implementing  ids...

Comment: I want to solve the problem with double keys with an secondary structure (lower part of the table) also done with arrays.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to implement your own hash table. Look up the data structure on Wikipedia to see how it's done